# Electron Updates with update.electronjs.org

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, updates

I have tried every single update service possible for electron none has worked for me i just want a simple auto update url for electron because ive built the app i've created a release and ive followed all naming conventions but when i go to the url i keep getting this error No updates found (needs asset containing win32-{x64,ia32,arm64} or .exe in public repository) my repository is public and it has an exe file is there any other configuration needed for update.electronjs.org

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask